# ionic 3 loadingcontroller enable backdrop dismiss not working

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have successfully created a loader using following code

```
presentLoading() {
    this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...',
      //duration: 3000,
      dismissOnPageChange: true,
      showBackdrop: true,
    }).present();
  }
```

but i am not able to place `enableBackdropDismiss` any where in code i don't know where to put it and how to use it to dismiss my loader

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like other propertive. When it is setted to `true`, user can dismiss your loading by tapping the backdrop. If you want to dismiss your loading in your code, you need create a varible to represent it:

```
presentLoading() {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...',
      //duration: 3000,
      dismissOnPageChange: true,
      showBackdrop: true,
      enableBackdropDismiss: true
    }).present();
    //Compute, ajax call or what ever you want
    //Dismiss loading
    loading.dismiss();
  }
```

Comment: i have tried doing that it gives following error:

Argument of type '{ content: string; dismissOnPageChange: true; showBackdrop: true; enableBackdropDismiss: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LoadingOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'enableBackdropDismiss' does not exist in type 'LoadingOptions'.

Comment: note that: you must use `,` not `;` to separate propertive

Comment: i am using your code only, still getting same error

Comment: Why you get this `{ content: string; dismissOnPageChange: true; showBackdrop: true; enableBackdropDismiss: boolean; }` It have `;`. My code only use `,`